# Rails 3: Getting CSRF Warning even though authenticity_token exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

On multiple parts of my site I'm receiving `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` in my log file, which is resetting my sessions. However, I have the authenticity tokens:

```
    Started POST "/check_out/shopping_cart_with_authenticated_user" for 10.189.254.5 at 2013-09-12 11:19:02 -0400
    Processing by CheckOutController#shopping_cart_with_authenticated_user as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rGcLQAR/s7zRNf2WEqkuD7ar8IXs0alt7szJKSfgLio="}
    SESSION VARIABLES ARE: {}
    WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

and here:

```
    Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"N1F53oN1fTv2Ysg/27biH14dDyTtkm2RinAUqSHwGAs=", "user"=>{"email"=>"liz@nsdfsdfsdfsry.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
    SESSION VARIABLES ARE: {"current_cart_id"=>55175183, "_csrf_token"=>"HzPm7DHLslbV76wJ3ahCqPkOO4bv5k5CkjKBe3C9WHE=", "flash"=>#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00000005f1e028 @used=#<Set: {}>, @closed=false, @flashes={}, @now=#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashNow:0x00000005e81570 @flash=#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00000005f1e028 ...>>>, "warden.user.user.key"=>["User", [358060], "$2a$12$VcSeYjhwx6JkgERnlN0clu"], "logged_in_by_password"=>true, "user_id"=>358060}
    WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

What's the deal? I'm using Rails generated forms. Here's an example of a Devise form I'm using:

```
            <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                <%= token_tag form_authenticity_token %>
              <div class="formField"><label for="email">Email <span>example: jane@example.com</span></label>
              <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :id => "email", :class => "textfield col" %></div>

              <div class="formField"><label for="password">Password <span>is cAsE sEnSiTiVe</span></label>
              <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "textfield col" %></div>



              <div><%= f.submit "Sign in", :disable_with => "Signing in&#8230;".html_safe,:id => 'log_in', :class => 'button-red-shiny full-width ' %></div>
            <% end %>
```

== UPDATE ==

So eventually I closed the browser and reopened it and it worked again... But it bothers me that this has happened on multiple occasions. Anyone know how I could prevent it from occurring again?

Comment: If you reload the page, does the authenticity token remain the same, or change every time?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSRF token isn't being matched between the client and the server. This causes this error to occur.